# Complex Numbers | $z=r(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)$, find the polar form of $\frac{1}{2}(z-\overline{z})$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

$z = r(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)$, find the polar form of $\frac{1}{2}(z-\overline{z})$. 
I know that $\overline{z} = r(\cos\theta - i \sin\theta)$ so I get: 
$$
\frac{1}{2}(z-\overline{z})
= \frac{1}{2} [ r(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta) - r(\cos\theta - i \sin\theta) ]
= \frac{1}{2} r (\ 2i  \sin\theta)
= r(i\sin\theta)
$$
I don't know how to continue from here because I need to get the polar form, which is
$r (\cos\alpha+i \sin\alpha)$. 
I also know $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\alpha=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ because $\frac{1}{2}(z-\overline{z})=i \ Im(z)$. 

I will be greatful for any kind of help.

Comment: As you wrote $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\alpha=\frac{3\pi}{2}$, then $\cos$ is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Just note that
$$r (i \sin \theta) = (r \sin \theta) \, i
$$
and that $r \sin \theta$ is a real number, which could be either positive or negative.

So the polar form is
$$\bigl(r \sin \theta\bigr) \bigl(\cos(\pi/2) + i \sin(\pi/2)\bigr) \quad\text{if $0 < \theta < \pi$}
$$
$$\bigl(-r \sin \theta \bigr) \bigl(\cos(3\pi/2) + i \sin(3\pi/2)\bigr) \quad\text{if $\pi < \theta < 2\pi$}
$$
By the way if $\theta = 0$ or $\pi$ then $z-\bar z = (r \sin \theta) \, i = 0$ so there is no well-defined angle.